# SSRS exposing the Data source name of a data set

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, datasource

Because we design in a multi tier release environment, we have similar data on 3 SQL servers.  We may have three copies of the same report directed to the different data bases.  We name the reports with the source in the name.  i.e. Report 1 UAT.  Users do not pay attention.  When a report is run and exported, you can no longer see the name so what looks like a production report could be a UAT copy.  What I am trying to do is add a placeholder in the title that lists the data source for the reports primary dataset.  I thought I would find a resource that said dataset1.datasource that returned the name I had assigned the data source at creation.  That does not appear to be the case. Any ideas how to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in SSRS that would let you use a property of the **Datasource**, but there is a `Globals!ReportName` field that you could use since you state that the source is in the environment:

> We name the reports with the source in the name. i.e. Report 1 UAT

Put a text box that uses the ReportName in it:

```
=Globals!ReportName
```